# Password protect a page with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm building a CMS with Firebase, but struggling to assess whether what I require is possible, or if I'm missing something.

What I require is the ability to password-protect a page only, and remember that browser as having access. A full user account (using the in built auth) is required to edit the content of the page, but only a password is required to view it.

I know I can use the auth flow with email, but am looking for the editor to be able to create a password for viewing only.

Is this possible, or should I look elsewhere?

Answer (score 7):

The way I commonly do this is a bit like Jeremy's answer, but simpler.

You ask the user for a password when they enter the page, and store that password locally (for reloads).

Then you store data in your database under a path that includes the password. So say that your password is `geheim`, you could store the data under:

```
data: {
  geheim: {
    value: "This is the secret value"
  }
}
```

Now you secure your database with rules like these:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "data": {
      "geheim": {
        ".read": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now somebody can only read the data at `/data/geheim` if they know the entire path. So you'll enter the `data` part in your code, but require them to enter `geheim` as the password. Then you attach a listener with:

```
firebase.database().ref("data").child(password).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

And if the user entered the correct value for `password`, this will read the value.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication only deals with authenticated user accounts.  It doesn't deal with simple password protection of content.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible, but as Doug's answer indicated, you'll have to do it outside normal means. Off the top of my head, the way I would accomplish this is...

- When a user enters a password, it stores the password in their local storage.
- On page load, or on password entry... pull the password from local storage
- Make a request to a Firebase cloud function, makes sure to include the password it just retrieved from local storage, and which page it is requesting content for
- Firebase cloud function validates password
- Firebase cloud function retrieves data for specific page
- Firebase cloud function returns said data
- Load data on front-end like normal

As you already identified, you should stick with the built-in Firebase auth for content editing.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely suggest Frank's answer because it's simple and it works. Btw the moral of the story is that you use the firebase Database to store you view-only password **but**, if you want to complicate your life because you need a strong view-only password system, the Authentication product provides the custom authentication method that you can integrate with your existing auth system (for example fb login). It obviously needs a server-side implementation that is a code that takes the password, check if it's valid and sends the token back to the Auth system.
Here more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth